# the webpack's resolve.alias is not work at dev running

Tags: webpack, vue.js

i use the vue-hackernews-2.0 to make a project

the project had a file which path is `server/middleware/bodyParser.js`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXVKO.png)

i want to give the path another name, so i add the resolve.alias with `'middleware': path.resolve(__dirname, '../server/middleware'),`

and use like this `let bodyParser = require('middleware/bodyParser.js');`
if it build, it work fine, but when i run `npm run dev`, it flow error like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4BzF.png)

has anyone know what happend? And how can i deal it?

Thank you

Comment: You did not link `require('middleware.bodyParser.js')` properly

Comment: i found the alias is not work on serverCompiler, but it work on clientCompiler,but why?